# Create a C++ table that accepts strings with spaces

Tags: c++

I'd like to create a console table out of this as a matter of exercise and to enhance my understanding of tables in C++.

[image: Table showing how inheritance works]

I have found what seemed like a good working table but I think fails because my strings contain spaces.

This one tested okay with the values that were provided in the example:

https://github.com/haarcuba/cpp-text-table

However, when I added a string such as "public members are public in derived class and can be accessed directly by member functions and nonmember functions" into a `t.add();`, it failed to print any of the table whatsoever.

I look forward to learning.

Comment: What are you asking? Do you have problems with code using inheritance?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to accept a string with spaces from user input, then you need to user the [getline() function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/).

```
getline(cin,variableToStoreIn);
```

If your question is about inheritance, please reword your question for clarity.